# Pass data to other website search

Tags: php, ajax, search

Is there a way to search on `www.qantas.com.au` or other sites that don't use GET method, from my own form?

I mean something like this : http://site.com/search.php?data=myData

I don't want to return result on my webpage, I just want to send data with a href

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the website, many forms may contain CSRF tokens intended to prevent this behavior (imagine if a third party site could 'submit' a form for you to another site, perhaps to trans fer money or write embarassing posts)

That said, for sites that don't implement this feature, it should be possible just to copy their form (from `<form>` to `</form>`) including the `action="/their/website/controller"` and `method="POST"` (if you want it posted)

If you want to design your own form that submits the same data, just make sure the input fields have a `name="blah"` the same as the form data value that you want to submit

AJAX is also an option if you dont want to use a form. (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)